# How do I find out more about socket files in /proc/fd?

Tags: networking, proc, socket

Looking in /proc/$mypid/fd/, I see these files

```
lrwx------ 1 cm_user cm_user 64 Oct 14 03:21 0 -> /dev/pts/36 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 cm_user cm_user 64 Oct 14 03:21 3 -> socket:[1424055856]
lrwx------ 1 cm_user cm_user 64 Oct 14 03:21 4 -> socket:[1424055868]
lrwx------ 1 cm_user cm_user 64 Oct 14 03:21 5 -> socket:[1424055882]
```

Because I have access to the code, I know these sockets are tied to TCP connections (one is a connection to port 5672 on some machine, another is a connection to port 3306 on some other machine), but I want to know which socket is tied to which connection. How can I do that?

More generally, how can I ask the OS what is at the other end of the socket?

Comment: Use `socat` ....

Comment: See also [Who's got the other end of this unix socketpair?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair/190606#190606)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10050/proc-pid-fd-x-link-number from info on how to read /proc/net et. al.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10050/proc-pid-fd-x-link-number for how to read and interpret /proc/net/tcp

Answer (score 88, accepted):

### Command lsof

A good option might be `lsof`. As `man lsof` states it is handy for obtaining information about `open files such as Internet sockets or Unix Domain sockets`.

---

### Using it

At first, get an overview about `/proc/$PID/fd/` and the listed socket numbers.
For example, `socket:[14240]` might interest you.

Then use `lsof -i -a -p $PID` to print a list of all network files `$PID` uses.

- `-i` produces a list of network files belonging to a user or process
- `-a` logically combines or AND's given parameters
- `-p $PID` selects info only about your process

A typical output for my browser running with a PID of `2543` might be:

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
browser 2543 pidi   55u  IPv4  14240      0t0  TCP  pidi.router.lan:55038->stackoverflow.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

and more similar lines.

Great! Now take a closer look at the `DEVICE` column. 
It matches our previously listed socket from `/proc/$PID/fd/`!
And thanks to the `NAME` section we can say what the other end of our socket is.

In a real world run you might get a good amount of output, but just filter or `grep` for your socket of interest.

I'm pretty sure one could combine all commands, but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted and accepted. I do see a socket showing up in lsof as "unix 0xffff88002704d380      0t0 1423733559 socket", how do I dig into what 0xffff88002704d380 is?

Comment: "unix 0xfff ..." seems like the kernel memory address of a unix_sock structure. This structure contains a pointer to your socket-end point. Take a look at `grep -rni ffff88002704d380 /proc`. somewhere under /proc/ may lie your answer, `cat` your file grep found. But dont pin me down on this... May be horrible wrong here.

Comment: `lsof` reads other information about the socket from `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/tcp6`, `/proc/net/udp`, and so on depending on socket type.

Comment: Does not work for me. I think you can reproduce it *(at least I can)* by first doing `sudo ls -l /proc/$(pidof wpa_supplicant)/fd | grep socket | wc -l` to confirm the process has "socket" descriptors. For me it has 17 of them. Then you do `sudo lsof -i -a -p $(pidof wpa_supplicant)`, and… nothing. Well, I got two warnings about `can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse` and `can't stat() fuse.portal`, but I doubt they're relevant. For one, `wpa_supplicant` has stdout/stderr redirected to some socket *(which is what I'm mainly interested in)*, and I don't think these "fuse" thingies could have a relation.

Comment: Okay, I figured: you need to replace `-i` option of the lsof command with `-U`. I.e. you use `sudo lsof -U -a -p $(pidof wpa_supplicant)`. Unfortunately combining `-i` doesn't seem to work, so one have to run both commands while searching for socket files. But turns out there's a better way! You have to use `ss -apn | grep your_socket` — unlike `lsof`, the `ss` command shows all types of sockets, unless you explicitly restrict it.