# What does it mean when a file descriptor is a link to a pipe?

Tags: pipe, ls, file-descriptors

When I look at `ls -la /proc/<pid>/fd`, I see that stdout is a link to a pipe:

```
lr-x------    1 admin    root            64 Jul  9 21:22 1 -> pipe:[1155]
```

What does it mean? Who is listening to this pipe? How can I watch this process's stdout?

Comment: "_How can I watch this process stdout_?" Is it your aim to "eavesdrop" on it? Or just to find out where the stream is going?

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10056/315749), that means that the standard output of the process whose PID is `<pid>` has been redirected to a [pipe](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_278) (a kind of [FIFO](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_163) with no representation in the filesystem hierarchy). `1155` is the pipe's inode number (on Linux you can look for `/proc/[pid]/fd/` in the [`proc(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page for more on this).

An example:

```
$ cat - | less
$ pgrep cat
187873
$ ls -l /proc/187873/fd/1
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Jul  9 22:23 /proc/187873/fd/1 -> 'pipe:[1624839]'
```

The standard output of `cat` is being redirected to the writing end of the pipe whose inode is `1624839`, while the standard input of `less` is being redirected from its reading end.

If we knew nothing about the process connected to the reading end of the pipe, we could search for all the processes that have it open (but note that we might not have the needed privileges to see them):

```
$ fuser -v /proc/187873/fd/1
                     USER   PID ACCESS COMMAND
/proc/187873/fd/1:   user  187873 F.... cat
                     user  187874 f.... less
```

And then confirm that `less` has it open (for reading):

```
$ ls -l /proc/187874/fd/0
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Jul  9 22:28 /proc/187874/fd/0 -> 'pipe:[1624839]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You find the other end of the pipeline (if the process is still alive) with

```
ls -l /proc/[1-9]*/fd 2>/dev/null | grep -B 3 -F 'pipe:[1155]'
```